# Azure Copy from TFS2017 to Azure VM Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0

Tags: tfs, json.net, azure-vm

I am a newbie playing with TFS so you may need to ExplainLikeIamFive what is going on with this.

I have been asked to upload a Blob file to Azure VM from using our onsite TFS build pipelines.

We are using TFS 2017 and the Azure File Copy task (version 1.0) in TFS.

I am getting the following error:

```
> 2020-07-31T09:07:45.4248226Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\5.7.0\AzureRM.psd1 -Global
> 2020-07-31T09:07:45.8779680Z ##[error]Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
> 2020-07-31T09:07:45.9092180Z ##[section]Finishing:  Azure Blob File Copy
```

I have the following in my machine.config file located in Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: Hi Did you try below solution to upgrade the azure powershell on your agent machine. How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the older version of azure powershell on your local agent machine. It is said the latest version of azure powershell fixed the error `Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json...'` Checkout [a similar issue here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6250) for more information.

You can have a try upgrading the azure powershell on your local agent machine to the latest version.

Click [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v6.2.1-June2018) download the latest 6.2.1 version. (azure powershell is a prerequisite for  [Azure File Copy](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/releases/m94/Tasks/AzureFileCopy/)  task).